# React unique key warning even with key set

Tags: reactjs

New to react, doing my first learning project beyond the tic-tac-toe examples.

Starting with displaying a table of data.  Table has a header and multiple rows.  I have a unique key for each row, and have a separate and distinct key for the header.  However no matter where I place the key i always get the warning.  Its not a showstopper but would like to know what i am missing as i am learning.

Below is the render of the main App component.  I added a key at the top div also but it makes no difference.

*** Interestingly enough when i use the React component viewer in Chrome, each component is shown and the keys are unique!

Any help appreciated.

```
  render() {
if (this.state.isFetching === true)
  return <div>Loading Please Wait....</div>
else {
  console.log(this.state.objData.teamId);
  return (
    <div className="App" key={this.state.objData.meetId}>
      <table>
        <thead >
          <GridHeader data={this.state.objData.filteredEvents} key={this.state.objData.teamId} />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.state.objData.athleteList.map((e) => {
              
              let athEvents = this.state.objData.athleteSignUps.filter(item => item.athleteId === e.athleteId);
              console.log(athEvents);

              return (
                <ItemData id={e} key={e.athleteId} />
              )
            }
            )
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: So the only place you need unique keys is when rendering arrays of components, and only the outermost element needs the key prop. Based on the code in your question, the only place that'd be relevant is rendering `ItemData`. However it looks like you already gave a key, so inside that try logging `e.athleteId` to see that they're all unique (I assume there's no duplicate athletes in the list). If those IDs are all unique, the problem will be elsewhere, so you need to narrow it down to where the error is occurring.

Comment: Appreciate the response!  Actual error in console is : Check the render method of `GridHeader`.  And correct all athletes id's are unique.  It's strange as in component viewer the GridHeader has a key and looks ok.

Comment: Ok so it's saying check the **render method** of `GridHeader`. So you need to look inside that component at what it's rendering. The `GridHeader` itself is only rendered once, so it doesn't need a key. Are you rendering any arrays *inside* `GridHeader`?

Comment: You, my friend are a genius.  Yes the header is dynamic and is coming from an array, I added the key to each td and the warning went away!  I am so happy and thankful right now.  Much appreciated, I learned a little more!